# Mailbox click slider

Tags: slide

If you have seen the mailbox app that dropbox has just bought you might have seen how you delete and archive mail with half and full slides (http://www.actualidadiphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Mailbox-2.jpg)

I would like to incorporate something like that into a website, could someone please give me some idea on how I would do this?

Comment: Which plattform ? IOS or Android ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/listview/listviewworkorders). Should be working in a mobile website.
Implementing it should be pretty easy as well. It is a matter of configuring the steps:

```
stages: [
    { percent: 25, color: 'crimson', icon: 'checkmark', action: function (li) {
        //do action1
    } },
    { percent: -25, color: 'olive', icon: 'clock', action: function (li) {
        //do action2
    } }
]
```